# Closure Compiler warning for FileReader and Blob - cannot fix it

Tags: javascript, filereader, google-closure-compiler

I run the following through Closure Compiler with advanced optimizations:

```
/**@type{Blob} */var blob = new Blob( ['[1,2]'], {type : 'text/html'} );
test(blob);


/** @param{Blob} a_blob */
function test(a_blob){
 /**@type{FileReader} */var filereader = new FileReader();
 filereader.onload = function(e){};
 filereader.readAsArrayBuffer(a_blob);
}
```

and I get:

```
WARNING - actual parameter 1 of FileReader.prototype.readAsArrayBuffer does not match formal parameter
found   : (Blob|null)
required: Blob
     filereader.readAsArrayBuffer(a_blob);
                                  ^
```

What can I do to fix this? Is this a bug in CC?

Comment: Looks like your code allows `a_blob` variable to be `null`. How is `test` called and with what value passed in?

Comment: As far as I know, I only pass in a Blob, otherwise wouldn't the @param{Blob} issue a warning (which it doesn't)?

Comment: I added a couple lines of code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Closure Compiler unfortunately assumes all object types are nullable unless you tell it otherwise using an `!`

```
/** @param{!Blob} a_blob */
function test(a_blob){
```

Comment: ... and /** @type{!Blob}

Comment: By way of extended explanation, the types that are not objects types are `number` and `string`. These are by default not nullable in the Closure Compiler.

Comment: I would call this a bug in Closure Compiler, but I can live with putting a ! in front of every annotation type. I use Closure Compiler and recommend it for type checking alone, but it has the feel of being buggy because of this and other weirdness. I am writing this comment because I hope the Google people on this project take note.

Comment: @DaveWalley The default nullability has been the subject of much discussion. It will eventually be changed. However, it requires updates to all of Closure-library and that is not a small task. For now, the recommendation is that every type annotation contain either a `?` or a `!` so as to be completely unambiguous.